# Select all elements with same class after an element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list, I want to select all "similar" items (i.e with same class) after an element:

```
<ul>
    <li class="x">foo</li>
    <li class="y" id="b">foo</li> <!-- From this... -->
    <li class="y">foo</li> <!-- ...can I select this?... -->
    <li class="y">foo</li> <!-- ...and this... -->
    <li class="x">foo</li> <!-- ...but not that... -->
    <li class="y">foo</li> <!-- ...and neither that... -->
</ul>
```

Can I select (with CSS only) all elements with `.y` class after element `#b`?
I don't know the position of any of the elements (and how many element there is), I just know the ID of the element I want to start with (`#b`) and the class I want to catch (`.y` after `#b` and before the next `.x`).

Can I write something in CSS to match this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `.y` after `#b`

That would be

```css
#b ~ .y
```

> and before the next `.x`

This is a little tricky. If there may be another `.x` element and you want to avoid styling `.y` elements that follow that `.x` element, you'll most probably need an overriding rule (after the first):

```css
#b ~ .y {
  /* Style all .y that follow #b */
}

#b ~ .x ~ .y {
  /* Revert styles for .y that follow the next .x after #b */
}
```

Comment: Wow! It works, I did not think it was really possible! Thanks!

Comment: Never underestimate the power of CSS :D

Comment: @TheYaXxE: It's a fine line :) The fact that an overriding rule is necessary here demonstrates a limitation: that there is no previous sibling (or "until next sibling") selector. It's strictly a design limitation however.

Comment: You could also write the revert style selector like this:
`#b ~ :not(.y) ~ .y`

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the selector for you. I am now using adjacent selector like

```
.y + .y {
  color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/skxcuugw/3/)

The above selector will only select elements which are adjacent to `.y` and  has a `class` of `.y`

Comment: I think OP wants the selection to start after `#b` (wherever it is in the list), and to end as soon as a non-`y` is found.

Comment: Thanks. The second exemple is what I want, but it only works with my example. As I said I dont know how many items are after. Here is a demo of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/skxcuugw/2/

Comment: @rap-2-h: Mr. Alien's answer will work without requiring an override if your .y following .x never appear more than once at a time (your examples contain only one .y per .x).